# read value from column and run query based on that

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have a table with 2 columns in my database: `name` and `families`, and both of them are `varchar`. for example:

```
name     families
----------------------
A        'B','C'
B        'A'
C        'A','B'
...
```

now I want to get the rows, the names of which are mentioned in the families column of the first row. I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM t JOIN (SELECT families FROM t WHERE name='A') AS z WHERE name IN (z.families)
```

but it does not return any row. what is the problem?

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store multiple values in a single column!

Comment: @Gordon so what is the best approach in my case? as you can see families are not unique, for example `B` is in the families column of both `A` and `C`

Answer (score 1):

You should have a table with one row per name and family:

```
name   family
 A       B
 A       C
 B       A
. . .
```

Then your query is simply:

```
select nf.*
from name_families nf join
     name_families nf2
     on nf2.family= nf.family and
        nf2.name = 'A' and
        nf2.name <> fn.name;
```

Comment: unfortunately it's absolutely not possible in my case. each person (name) can have only one row due to some restrictions.

Comment: @Soheil . . . This would be in a *different* table.

Comment: yes, many to many relation can be implemented in that way but our restriction is to avoid extra table as well. we have millions of rows and that extra table will create an extremely large number of rows. why simply the data stored in one column can't be used in my query (like what I have mentioned in question)?

Answer (score 1):

Use the function [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) in a self join like tis:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.name
FROM t t1 INNER JOIN t t2
ON FIND_IN_SET(t1.name, REPLACE(t2.families, '''', ''))
WHERE t2.name = 'A'
```

Or:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.name
FROM t t1 INNER JOIN t t2
ON FIND_IN_SET(QUOTE(t1.name), t2.families)
WHERE t2.name = 'A'
```

Or without a join:

```
SELECT name
FROM t 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(QUOTE(name), (SELECT families FROM t WHERE name = 'A'))
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=356533175b46feaf0cf3e81e34feb5a3).
Results:

> | name |
> | --- |
> | B |
> | C |

Comment: many thanks. but the data in families column are saved in this format: 'A','B',... (notice the quotations!)

Comment: @Soheil I did not notice that and it is odd. See my edited answer.